# Sql Server stored procedure filter by date?

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I am new to writing stored procedures so I am a bit stuck- 
I would like to write a procedure where I would want to filter by date. I have a column which saves datetime but I only want to match the date part from the datetime value. How do I go about it? This is what I tried so far.
I have a column called trxdate which is of type datetime.

```
USE [CAFFE]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[p_paymentrecordsbydateandpaymentmode]    Script Date: 3/3/2017 11:32:19 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[p_paymentrecordsbydateandpaymentmode]
(
    @Country        VARCHAR(20),
    @BankID         VARCHAR(20),
    @ModeOfPayment  VARCHAR(20),
    @TrxDate        datetime
)
AS
    SELECT      
        MobileNumber,
        ModeOfPayment,
        Branch,
        ReceiptNo,
        Amount,
        TrxDate

    FROM tb_TransactionRequests(NOLOCK)
    WHERE @ModeOfPayment=ModeOfPayment and  @TrxDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),TrxDate,111)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try modify WHERE clause like this:

```
WHERE @ModeOfPayment=ModeOfPayment and  @TrxDate = cast(TrxDate as date)
```

and pass argument to procedure as

```
@TrxDate        date
```

proc call will look as

```
[dbo].[p_paymentrecordsbydateandpaymentmode] 1,1,'modeOfPayment','20170303'
```

Comment: @DmitryCat- How do i change the procedure such that i can fetch records within a date range and fetch the data within that date?

Comment: if i actually understand you, u need try cast(TrxDate as date) between \@date1 and \@date2

Answer (score 0):

You actually dont need to convert to varchar if stored procedure parameter and table database type is datetime. As below

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[p_paymentrecordsbydateandpaymentmode]
(
    @Country        VARCHAR(20),
    @BankID         VARCHAR(20),
    @ModeOfPayment  VARCHAR(20),
    @TrxDate        datetime
)
AS
    SELECT      
        MobileNumber,
        ModeOfPayment,
        Branch,
        ReceiptNo,
        Amount,
        TrxDate

    FROM tb_TransactionRequests(NOLOCK)
    WHERE @ModeOfPayment=ModeOfPayment and  @TrxDate = TrxDate
```

Answer (score 0):

You can isolate date/time from a `datetime` field by using the following `CAST` actions:

```
-- Select date
SELECT CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE);

-- Select time
SELECT CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME);
```